# Swashbuckle parameters in path forced to required

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swashbuckle, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

I am having an issue where if I try to force swashbuckle to understand the parameter is part of the path, it forces it to required.

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("test/{format}/{baseKey?}")]
[Route("test/{format}/{baseKey}/{apiKey}/{year}/{code}/{month}/{includeImages?}")]
[Produces("application/json", "application/xml")]
public async Task<List<TestItem>> Test([FromRoute] string format, [FromRoute] string baseKey, [FromRoute] string apiKey, [FromRoute] string year, [FromRoute] string code, [FromRoute] string month, [FromRoute] bool includeImages = false)
```

But even the item that is marked with `= false` is still marked as required.
Further to this, .net core used `?` in it's routes to define a non-required item so I'm a little confused why Swashbuckle doesn't respect this.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I have dug through the [documentation of swashbuckle](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore) and have identified that
I need to install the `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Annotations` from NuGet
Then add this to startup.cs:

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
   ...
   c.EnableAnnotations();
});
```

Then do similar to the following:

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult GetProducts([FromQuery, SwaggerParameter("Search keywords", Required = true)] string keywords)
```